# How to translate this raw query to Django ORM

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model where we have candidates, languages and language Level entities:

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser)
  telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
  postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Language(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class LanguageLevel(models.Model):
  candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate)
  language = models.ForeignKey(Language)
  level = models.IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=LANGUAGE_LEVEL, default=0)
```

My raw query is:

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(c.id) as total
FROM candidates as c
  JOIN language_level as ll ON ll.candidate_id=c.id
  JOIN languages as l ON ll.language_id=l.id
WHERE ((ll.level >=1 AND l.id = 1 ) OR
       (ll.level >=1 AND l.id = 2 ) OR
       (ll.level >=1 AND l.id = 3 ) OR
       (ll.level >=3 AND l.id = 4 ) OR
       (ll.level >=3 AND l.id = 5 ) OR
       (ll.level >=2 AND l.id = 6 ))
GROUP By c.id
```

I need to be able to sort the results by the the total field, and I also need to be able to display that total in the template. Somehow I need to create a list of bigger objects that combines those 3 entities + the group by.

Any idea what's the best approach? I tried getting the ids of the candidates and do just a Candidates.objects.find(id__in = ids) but there is no way later to sort this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't try to translate raw SQL. Describe the results you need in terms of the objects you have.

Comment: A basically need to list all the candidates that speak English and Spanish (for instance), where their level is equals or greater than intermediate. And then sort them by the ones that have better level giving percentage ... for instance if you speak both at the required level 100%, if you speak one 50%. So that's easy to do with SQL ... but I'm finding it a bit confusing with Django without using raw query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Candidate.objects.filter(
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id__in=(1, 2, 3)) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=1)) |
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id__in=(4, 5)) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=3)) |
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id=6) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=2))
)).values('id').annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

`values` will only return the `id` of each candidate with a calculated total as `total`.

If you want to get all of the fields (not only id), you can remove `.values('id')` as:

```
Candidate.objects.filter(
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id__in=(1, 2, 3)) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=1)) |
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id__in=(4, 5)) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=3)) |
    Q(Q(languagelevel__language__id=6) & Q(languagelevel__language__level__gte=2))
)).annotate(total=Count('id'))
```

Comment: Actually the previous response made more sense because I need to access the whole Candidate object to display it in the template. I'll give it a go ASAP.. but it looks pretty good to me. –

Comment: I based my code on this answer. Really helpful .values('id') not needed as I wanted the whole entities. Good one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see how your SQL does what you describe in your comment. However, this code does something similar to that description.

```
from django.db.models import Max
Candidate.objects.filter(
    languagelevel__language__name__in=['English', 'Spanish'],
    languagelevel__level__gte=2
).annotate(max_level=Max('languagelevel__level')).order_by('max_level')
```

Comment: If you run my query you get something like
c.id 5 => total languages 2, c.id 3 => total languages 3 
It basically tells you the candidateId, and the number of the languages from the query that the candidate has.

The problem with your code is that applies the same filter for all the languages when each language could have a different filter. But It's a starting point... I'll check that approach and see if I can expand it.